# Add plotbonds to Gaps defined by GapSize in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add background color to gaps in data to be more visible on large intervals, I know that I can do that by adding plotbonds with the color I want, the problem is I don't have the start and end of the gap because it is created by defining the GapSize and GapUnit (no dates with null data, juste a gap in the dates).
I tried adding the plotbonds by calculating the difference between the dates and comparing it to the tickInterval but no luck so far,

here is an example of gaps set with gapsize

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            gapSize: 1
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-gapsize

Is there a simpler way of doing this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts internally adds null points to create gaps. You can get the calculated null points and based on their values, create plot-bands.

For example:

```
let plotBands = [];
let allowChartUpdate = true;

(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.area.prototype, 'getGraphPath', function(proceed, points) {
        const xAxis = this.xAxis;
        plotBands = [];

        points.forEach((p, index) => {
            if (p.isNull) {
                plotBands.push({
                    from: points[index - 1] ? points[index-1].x : xAxis.min,
                    to: points[index + 1] ? points[index+1].x : xAxis.max,
                    color: 'red'
                });
            }
        });

        return proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        events: {
            render: function() {
                // prevent infinity loop
                if (allowChartUpdate) {
                    allowChartUpdate = false;
                    this.xAxis[0].update({plotBands});
                    allowChartUpdate = true;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jz0n28om/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: thank you ppotaczek, this is in fact the solution with a plugin on the render function, It is a bit complicated to adapt to what I'm working on, knowing that I wanted to implement it with the .NET wrapper of Highcharts, I will see if can find a solution